# WordPress feature image using if statement inside the img src attribute

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am accessing the feature image of a custom post type in WordPress by using an if has_post_thumb function. Everything works great except the trailing >" in the img tag is actually displaying on the page. Am I just writing it wrong? I have to keep the php inside the src attribute because there is some important Bootstrap classes inside the img tag. Please see code below:

```
                    <!-- create new loop and access custom post type for services using wordpress fxn -->
                    <!-- create var called loop and store a WP array for custom post type (CPT) services offered, ordered by id and ascending -->
                    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'accolades', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC') ); ?>

                    <!-- check to see if loop has posts and access posts from CPT. Same for all CPT -->
                    <?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                        <!-- no acf used below it is all native WP using CPT -->
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <!-- check if there is a post thumbnail img or feature image. this grabs the feature img if there is one below. add an else statement to the if to display image if none uploaded -->
                                    <img class="img-responsive img-circle" src="<?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ){ the_post_thumbnail(); } ?>">
                                </div><!-- /.col-sm-3 -->
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <blockquote>
                                    <!-- CPT content in content editor -->
                                        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                                        <!-- CPT title -->
                                        <small><?php the_title(); ?></small>
                                    </blockquote>
                                </div><!-- /.col-sm-9 -->
                            </div><!-- /.row -->
                        </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->

                    <!-- close the while loop -->
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: `<?php echo ((has_post_thumbnalil()) ? the_post_thumbnail() : '' )?>`

Comment: the_post_thumbnail displays an image - I think you need to use <?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'you image size here' ); ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the_post_thumbnail() function will already return the image not the url. Use the_post_thumbnail_url() instead.

Please refer,https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail_url

Comment: That worked! No more trailing "> being displayed on webpage. Thank you

Comment: @GingaRanga, I am glad it worked. Please accept the answer if you think it solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry I have a reputation less than 15 so my up votes are counted but not displayed publicly. I HAVE up voted though. Thanks

Comment: @GingaRanga, hey no worries. It was not about upvoting but accepting the answer. Also, it was not only for this question. For all the questions you post in SO, if you think any of the answer solved your issue, you can always accept the answer by clicking on the grey tick on the left. Please refer, http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this :

```
if(has_post_thumbnail()){
  echo "<img class='img-responsive img-circle' src='your image'>"
}
else{
   echo "<img class='img-responsive img-circle' src='your image'>"
}
```

OR

```
<?php echo ((has_post_thumbnalil()) ? the_post_thumbnail() : '' )?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like this:

```
 <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 
 'thumbnail' ); ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $url ?>" />
```